# Can I use "that" in two different senses in the same sentence?

Tags: word-usage, relative-pronouns, syntax

I'm writing an essay comparing and contrasting various culture differences between American and Japanese culture via personal account and I want to use this sentence to help describe the food. Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> Many other meals in Japan were similar **in that** they had a larger variety of food **than that** of many American meals.

Comment: I'd say it's fine; there's just a few redundant phrases.

Comment: We don't do proofreading here, but if you can narrow down what you're concerned about ("in that"? the comparisons using "many"? something else?), that would be fine.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Yes, thats more what I mean, thank you.

Comment: @MorellaAlmann: Er, which of those did you mean?

Comment: @NathanTuggy Right, sorry -Its been a long day :) -. I mean is the use of the in that and than that in the same sentence a bit unnecessarily complicated?

Comment: You can use the same word in as many senses as you want in the same sentence, for example, *[That that is, is. That that is not, is not. Is that it? It is.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That_that_is_is_that_that_is_not_is_not_is_that_it_it_is)*, or *[It is true for all that that that that that that that refers to is not the same that that that that refers to](https://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Power_of_7/7_Thats_2948.htm)*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a lot of "different" in one sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113561/how-to-use-a-lot-of-different-in-one-sentence)