# How to use a lot of "different" in one sentence?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, redundancy

> "Different people, the same people with different mood or emotion... all will make the same type of tea has different smelling and flavour."

Does this sound wired? Could you help me to do anything to improve this?

Comment: You could change it this way: *Different people —the same people with various moods or emotions— all will make the same type of tea that has another smelling and flavor*. But the sentence does not make sense to me well.

Comment: Did you mean "wierd" (strange) or "wired" (the result of your consuming a lot of caffeine)?

Answer (score 1):

It's not wrong to repeat a word if you want to emphasize its importance in the sentence:

> On *different* days, the *same* person can make the *same* tea in the *same* way but still end up with the tea having a *different* aroma and flavor.

Here the repetition of "same" and "different" helps clarify what you are trying to say.  The order of the phrases in the sentence can establish an interesting *rhythm*, but that's more about good *writing* than good *grammar*.

Otherwise, if a synonym (or two) is available you can use that instead of repeating the same word.  However, for "different", all of the synonyms (diverse, various, etc.) have varying nuances which I think don't work as well here.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your sentence is saying

> **Different** people with **different** moods or emotions will make **different** smelling and tasting tea.

and is emphasizing there there may be many different factors resulting in many different teas.

There is nothing wrong with using "different' several times, it would the same as saying

> **French** people with **French** moods or emotions will make **French** smelling and tasting tea.

meaning the tea will be very dependently French.  If you did not want to repeat "different" you would use a synonym instead

> > **Different** people with **various** moods or emotions will make **distinct** smelling and tasting tea.